# GCP Cloud Sql extracting query duration with regular expression

Tags: regex, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, stackdriver

[image: Stackdriver logging metric creator, trying to parse textPayload of logs to create graphs of query responses]
I currently have a regular expression that is not accepted in GCP Stackdriver Logging Metric Editor.
`(?<=duration: )(-?[0-9]+(?:[,.][0-9]+)?)(?= ms)` where I get the feedback `Regular expression must be valid and include exactly one non-empty match group, indicated by parentheses.`.
Link to where I created it initially: [regexr.com/4t3hl](http://regexr.com/4t3hl)
`"[19087]: [612-1] db=test_database,user=test LOG:  duration: 0.877 ms  statement: COMMIT;"`
Does anyone know what I need to do to extract query response times using this regex?

Comment: You have one capturing group already. You could omit the lookarounds and use matches instead keeping the current capturing group `\bduration: (-?[0-9]+(?:[,.][0-9]+)?) ms\b`

Comment: Hi there! I'm working in finding why the GUI shows that to your expression. Allow us 24 hours while we see if this is caused by an error on the GUI or if we need more information from you.

Comment: Error says you can only have ONE capturing group - see the simplified regexp: https://regexr.com/4t4en